# DiscordJS v12 - How can i have to args.slice .join(" ") Variables

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a command were it require you to put in a 3 digit number and a comment but how can I have both of those. Like if I run `.onboard <@user> [call-sign] [comments]` how can I have both the call-sign part and the comments park in the command. Cause I have that right now as shown below in the code and when I run the command it comes out like this

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const ms = require("ms");
const botconfig = require("../../botconfig.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.delete();

    let leoRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].leo_role);
    let cadetRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].cadet_role);
    if (!cadetRole) return console.log("Role not found (Config: 'leo_setup - cadet_role')");
    if (!leoRole) return console.log("Role not found (Config: 'leo_setup - leo_role')");

    if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].supervisor_role) && !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].command_role) && !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].high_command_role) && !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") && !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].asst_commish_role)) return message.channel.send('Invalid permissions.').then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error)

    let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    let callSign = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    let comments = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please put a valid member or a user ID for me to onboard").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
    if (!user) return message.channel.send("Sorry, I was unable to find this user.")
    //if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please put a valid member or a user ID for me to onboard").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
    //if (!callSign) return message.channel.send("Please enter in the call-sign.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
    if (user.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === botconfig["leo_setup"].leo_role)) return message.channel.send('This member is already Law Enforcement').then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
    if (user.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send('Why are you trying to onboard yourself?').then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
    if (user.user.bot) return message.channel.send('You can\'t onboard a bot').then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
    if (user.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || user.roles.highest.rawPosition >= message.guild.me.roles.highest.rawPosition) return message.channel.send("You cannot onboard this member").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);

    if(botconfig["module_toggles"].leo_module) {
        const logEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`LEO Onboarding Log`, botconfig["bot_setup"].embed_logo_cropped)
        .setThumbnail(botconfig["bot_setup"].embed_logo_cropped)
        .setDescription(`**Onboarder:** <@${message.author.id}> \n\n**Cadet:** <@${user.id}>\n\n**Cadet ID:** ${user.id}\n\n**Comments:** ${comments || "No Comments"}`,)
        /*.addField(
            { name: `Onboarder:`, value: `<@${message.author.tag}>` },
            { name: `Cadet:`, value: `<@${user.name}>` },
            { name: `Cadet ID:`, value: user.id },
            { name: `Comments:`, value: comments },
        )*/
        .setFooter(message.guild.name)
        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
        .setTimestamp();

        let onboardLogChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["channel_setup"].onboard_log_channel);
        if (!onboardLogChannel) return console.log("Channel not found (Config: 'onboard_log_channel')");
        onboardLogChannel.send(logEmbed);
    }

    await(user.roles.add(leoRole.id));
    await(user.roles.add(cadetRole.id));


}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "onboard"
}
```

Comment: please give an example input you'd like and what you expect as output.  like: 321 this_is_the_comment?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know with what you need help with, but why not do

```
let callsign = args[1]
let comments = args[2]
```

And if the arguments have spaces in them, use ',' to separate them.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to explain it but this did help and its working now thank you.

Comment: @mrzeny Please mark the answer as 'answered'